# Format text input field without decimal dart

Tags: flutter, dart, formatting

I am trying to show a number string as a currency format in a FormField. Am using `inputFormatter` to achieve this. I want string to return this way: `1,000` but instead it returns with decimal e.g `1,000.00`

```
 inputFormatters: [
                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                    CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter()
                  ],
```

**CurrencyFormatterClass**

```
class CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CurrencyPtBrInputFormatter({this.maxDigits});
  final int maxDigits;

  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }

    if (maxDigits != null && newValue.selection.baseOffset > maxDigits) {
      return oldValue;
    }

    int value = int.parse(newValue.text);
    final formatter = new  NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: "en");
    String newText = "N" + formatter.format(value / 100);
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to int first, then to string:

```
double doubleNum = 1000.00;
int intNum = d.toInt();
yourValue = intNum.toString();
```

or as a one line:

```
String value= 1000.00.toInt().toString();
```

You can write var which you get the your value instead of 1000.00.